# Adding different templates in a table with angular 2

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I am building a generic table control that I would like to be able to use across many different forms. However some of the different rows will need different templates. The template tag is something that I just don't quite understand.

What i am trying to accomplish is if it is not a calendar then do one thing if it is do another thing.

My attempt:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
  <td *ngIf="canEditRecord">
    <a class="btn fa fa-pencil-square" (click)="navigateToEdit(row.id)"></a>
  </td>
  <td *ngFor="let column of columns" [innerHTML]="getPropertyValue(row, column.propertyName)"></td>
  <td *ngIf="canDelete && canEditRecord">
    <a class="btn fa fa-trash-o" (click)="deleteItem(row.id)"></a>
  </td>
</tr>


<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
  <td *ngFor="let day of row">{{day.dayNumber}}</td>
</tr>
```

Then I tried

```
<template>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <td *ngIf="canEditRecord">
      <a class="btn fa fa-pencil-square" (click)="navigateToEdit(row.id)"></a>
    </td>
    <td *ngFor="let column of columns" [innerHTML]="getPropertyValue(row, column.propertyName)"></td>
    <td *ngIf="canDelete && canEditRecord">
      <a class="btn fa fa-trash-o" (click)="deleteItem(row.id)"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>


<template>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <td *ngFor="let day of row">{{day.dayNumber}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>

Then I tried


<tr *ngif="!isCalendar" *ngFor="let row of rows">
  <td *ngIf="canEditRecord">
    <a class="btn fa fa-pencil-square" (click)="navigateToEdit(row.id)"></a>
  </td>
  <td *ngFor="let column of columns" [innerHTML]="getPropertyValue(row, column.propertyName)"></td>
  <td *ngIf="canDelete && canEditRecord">
    <a class="btn fa fa-trash-o" (click)="deleteItem(row.id)"></a>
  </td>
</tr>


<tr *ngif="isCalendar" *ngFor="let row of rows">
  <td *ngFor="let day of row">{{day.dayNumber}}</td>
</tr>
```

Angular2 will not let me use `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` in the same statement. Then I thought that I would do something similar `*ngIf` with `[ngSwitch]` it didn't like this for the same reason as `*ngIF` on `*ngCase`. Can someone please tell me the best way to do this. Please note that I am sure that i will have more templates later in building this, so I think that i should be able to reuse the same solution later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not allowed to use two structural template (`*`) statements on one element. To avoid having redundant elements you can use the `ng-container` component to get what you want:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!isCalendar">
    <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
        <td *ngIf="canEditRecord"><a class="btn fa fa-pencil-square" (click)="navigateToEdit(row.id)"></a></td>
        <td *ngFor="let column of columns" [innerHTML]="getPropertyValue(row, column.propertyName)"></td>
        <td *ngIf="canDelete && canEditRecord"><a class="btn fa fa-trash-o" (click)="deleteItem(row.id)"></a></td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should have a look at the [Template guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html). Specifically the section about the [template tag](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#star-template).

That said. The * syntax is really just a shortcut for the template usage. You need to look up the directive you want to use for both `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` since each have slightly different properties you need to set. **The good thing is, you can nest these template components as you see fit without adding any extra dom elements :)**

The easiest is *ngIf (`*ngIf="!isCalendar"`):

```
<template [ngIf]="!isCalendar">
```

You can also do *ngFor (`*ngFor="let row of rows"`)

```
<template ngFor let-row [ngForOf]="rows">
```

Go nuts and nest these around your normal html elements or even angular components :)